# Identify date format SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, datetime-format

I have plenty of columns with timestamps in the following `nvarchar` format '2016-11-22T20:16:32.573000Z' or 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.[sss]Z' and I need to convert the column type into date and time format.

I know there have been many questions asked about converting string to datetime conversions in SQL Server (Azure) using `CAST` or `CONVERT`. But I seem to be unable to identify the right style:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

The format looks like ISO 8601 style but e.g. style numbers 126 and 127 don't see to work. So which style should I use to be able to successfully convert the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That format is unambiguous but has more digits of precision than `datetime` can accommodate.

`CONVERT(datetime2,'2016-11-22T20:16:32.573000Z')` works fine without specifying a style, and you should be avoiding `datetime` in new work anyway. (Specifying styles 126 or 127 at this point is also fine if you want to, but unnecessary)

Comment: Yes that seemed to do the trick. Had a brief look into the datetime2 data type and from what I understand it should be indeed the preferred above datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if an update SQL statement with something like this in it might help to populate a new date field and a new time field:

```
SUBSTRING(MyLongDateTimeStringField,1,10) AS MyNewDateField,
SUBSTRING(MyLongDateTimeStringField,12,8) AS MyNewTimeField
```